# How to check if a matrix transfer function is in Hardy-infinity space?

Tags: matrices, control-theory, hardy-spaces

Just like the question says. For instance if I have a matrix transfer function $$\mathbf{G}(s) = \begin{bmatrix}s & -s \\ T & s \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
where  $T$ is a positive constant, how can I tell whether it is in Hardy-infinity space? Is there any other way than just verifying that $||\mathbf{G}(s)||_{\infty} < \infty$

Comment: You just verify the boundedness. Note that the matrix norm is bounded if and only if each entry is bounded. Since $T$ is a constant, the question reduces to: is $s$ bounded?

Comment: Is $s$ bounded? I mean, in frequency analysis of the system $s$ becomes simply $j\omega$. So if by bounded you mean is $|s| < M$, for some constant $M$ then the answer is no.

Comment: I believe only proper transfer functions belong to $H_\infty$ space. Clearly, your transfer function matrix is not.

Comment: For LTI causal systems having a finite $H_\infty$ norm is equivalent to being stable.